# Update custom object field on submit

Tags: apex

I have a Visualforce Page that that has a submit button on it.  When the user clicks the submit button I want to update a custom object's (Custom Obj = Leadership_Ready__c) field (field = Automated_TP_Status__c) with the text "Submitted".

Firstly, is this the best way to do it? And secondly, can you see what I'm doing wrong?

**Error message:**

> "An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has
>   been notified."

```
try {
                // Query for Leadership_Ready__c
                Leadership_Ready__c queriedContact = [SELECT Automated_TP_Status__c From Leadership_Ready__c where Id = :prodId ];

                // Update the Automated_TP_Status__c
                queriedContact.Automated_TP_Status__c = 'submitted';


                // Make two separate calls 
                // 1. This call is to update the Automated_TP_Status__c.
                update queriedContact;

            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred. PRODID:' + prodId);
            }
```

Comment: The error message you received is the standard error message, not the one you wrote. Try enabling [Development Mode](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_dev_mode.htm&type=0) and check your stack trace. You might also want to open the [Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console.htm&type=0) and check your logs.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  Very helpful.  This is the error message I got.
Visualforce Error:

System.LimitException: DML currently not allowed
Class.eventsCon.<init>: line 67, column 1

67. 'code'     update queriedContact; 'code'

Comment: If you are doing this in the constructor that would be one reason why (you can't do DML in the constructor, use the page action) or if the page is annotated with readOnly